# Removing CV qualifiers when deducing types using declytype

Tags: c++, decltype, type-deduction

I have a constant declared as following:

```
const auto val = someFun();
```

Now I want another variable with same type of 'val' but without the constant specification.

```
decltype(val) nonConstVal = someOtherFun();
// Modify nonConstVal, this is error when using decltype
```

Currently decltype keeps the constness. How to strip it?

Comment: The `<type_traits>` contains a [`remove_cv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv) trait, which you could use.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for!

Comment: In addition to Jarod42's answer and Bo's comment, please note `auto nonConstVal = someOtherFun()` could simply suffice and be more readable, depending on the rest of your code. Unless, of course, `someOtherFun()` returns something that is *not quite* the return type of `someFun()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `<type_traits>`

You may use in C++14:

```
std::remove_cv_t<decltype(val)> nonConstVal = someOtherFun();
```

or in C++11

```
std::remove_cv<decltype(val)>::type nonConstVal = someOtherFun();
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/rvGGNJ)